# What about multithreading/multiprocessing in BeautifulSoup and Python 3?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, pool, multitasking

So I messing around with **BeautifulSoup**. I wrote some code and, with your permision past it here. With the following question - Is there any way use multithreading or multiprocessing to speed it up? Bet this code is far from the ideal :)
Should **Pool** be used for such ocasions?

ps. I took this website as an example.

Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

pages = [str(i) for i in range(100,2000)]
for page in pages:
    html = requests.get('https://statesassembly.gov.je/Pages/Members.aspxMemberID='+page).text
    def get_page_data():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('h1').text
    title = soup.find(class_='gel-layout__item gel-2/3@m gel-1/1@s').find('h2').text
    data = {'name': name,
            'title': title,
            }

    return (data)

data = get_page_data()
with open('Members.csv','a') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow((data['name'],
                    data['title'],
                    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brute force a government website can be an illegal in some countries. please make sure you read copyright laws of your country and the country you are fetching data from.

first of all please divide your list into parts after that make threads of it to parallel execute them.

## Python program to illustrate the concept of threading

```
import threading 
import os 

def task1(): 
    print("Task 1 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
    print("ID of process running task 1: {}".format(os.getpid())) 

def task2(): 
    print("Task 2 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name)) 
    print("ID of process running task 2: {}".format(os.getpid())) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # print ID of current process 
    print("ID of process running main program: {}".format(os.getpid())) 

    # print name of main thread 
    print("Main thread name: {}".format(threading.main_thread().name)) 

    # creating threads 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t1') 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2, name='t2')   

    # starting threads 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 

    # wait until all threads finish 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join()
```

Comment: Thank You for caution about website. As I mentioned I took it for example. I foun your solution helpful. But yesterday I managed to implement a Pool’s map function, completely changed my script. So now I’m testing it. Thank you for your help. Good luck.